# SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True not working in Django:

Tags: django, zap

I have set the following code in my `settings.py`:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

even though the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY) say this is default.

Then I use `./manage.py runserver` and run OWASP Zap scanner on the site. But OWASP zap says that the cookie was set without the HttpOnly flag:

[image]

I also have this problem when I server the site with `gunicorn` and `nginx`. How can I get this flag set?

Using `django 1.8`; the page `accounts/login` is managed by `django-registration-redux`, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cookie you have highlighted in the screenshot is not the session cookie, it's the csrf cookie. There is a separate setting [`CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly) for this cookie. Unlike `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`, `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` defaults to `False`, so you need to add it in your settings.

```
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

Note that setting the csrf cookie to http only will make it trickier to do ajax post requests. Instead of using the cookie, your javascript will have to pull the csrf token from the page instead.

Comment: Is it safe to say that setting `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True` does not have serious security implications on an https-only website?

Comment: I'm not a security expert so I don't feel qualified to give a definitive answer. If you do set `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=True`, malicious javascript can still load the token from a page where the token is in the html. There's a related [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!searchin/django-developers/CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY%7Csort:relevance/django-developers/nXjfLd8ba5k/H1Kn8gtCbS0J) on the Django-developers mailing list.